# Wordpress login not working

Tags: admin, wp-admin, login

Ok so i needed to add a new user to my wordpress site DreamersCorp.org. When registering in the wp-admin screen it worked. I then proceeded to login and it failed. I then reset the password. I once again proceeded to login and it failed. I tried to login to the admin account and that to failed. In unsure what happened but now i can't even login to my website.

Comment: Did you clear your cache and cookies?

Comment: @seamus yea i did. I'll try restarting the computer to. Is just a really weird issue

Comment: Have you added users in the past?  Have you recently added any plugins?

Comment: Nope. This was my first time adfing users and it's the same plugina

Comment: useful WP codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble